# hyperlinks blocked on opening as a new tab - django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a python script (A.py) that accepts users input via form and runs another python script (B.py). B.py stores html formatted results into a folder named yyyymmdd.

The file generated by B.py is like "results_hhmmss.html", so every time B.py script is executed a new has html file is created.

As per my urls.py code below, visiting 127.0.0.1:8888 takes me to home_page. Further, once i submit form using a button in the home_page, the scripts gets executed successfully and a result file is generated.

I am not sure how to render the results as the results file name keeps varying.

Hence, i tried keeping a constant page results.html and add a hyper-link to file results_hhmmss.html within results.html.

I tried providing href= with absolute path of results_hhmmss.html file and the hyperlink can be seen when hovered pointing to
`file:///Users/msh0047/tmp/welcome/20200627/results_231603.html`
However, upon clicking the hyperlink, nothing happens.
When I open the hyperlink in a new tab, i see blank page with "**about:blank#blocked**" in the address bar.

I also tried providing href= with relative path of the results_hhmmss.html file and the hyperlink can be seen when hovered pointing to
http://127.0.0.1:8888/20200627/results_231603.html , clicking the hyperlink throws error saying  **Page not found(404)** and **The current path, 20200627/results_231603.html didn't match any of these.** (these = any of the url path listed in urls.py).

However, I can open that results_hhmmss.html file by directly type/paste the absolute path into the address bar.

I am not sure what wrong i am doing here, can you please help guiding me please.

urls.py contents as below:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home_page),
    path('results/', views.generate_results_file, name='run_generate_file_script'),
]
```

views.py contents file as below:

```py
def generate_results_file(request):

    hhmmss = str(datetime.now().strftime("%H%M%S"))
    yyyymmdd = str(datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d"))

    results_filename = "templates/results_" + hhmmss + ".html"
    ls_cmd = "pwd; ls -lart | tee " + results_filename

    output = subprocess.Popen(ls_cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    wait_for_sec = request.POST.get('seconds')
    time.sleep(int(wait_for_sec))

    return render(request, results_filename)



def home_page(request):
    # Purpose: Just display welcome home_page.html
    return render(request, 'welcome/home_page.html')
```

Thanks heaps in advance for taking time to read this post and willingness to help.

Answer (score 0):

It is http and not https, and "about:blank#blocked" is a browser security setting. Could it be that the browser security settings need to be adjusted?